# Get all categories with number of associated records with where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So I have two tables:

`Categories`

```
-------------------
| Id | Name       |
-------------------
| 1  | Category1  |
-------------------
| 2  | Category2  |
-------------------
| 3  | Category3  |
-------------------
```

`Products`

```
--------------------------------------------
| Id | CategoryId | Name     | CreatedDate |
--------------------------------------------
| 1  |     1      | Product1 | 2017-05-05  |
--------------------------------------------
| 1  |     1      | Product2 | 2017-05-06  |
--------------------------------------------
| 2  |     2      | Product3 | 2017-12-21  |
--------------------------------------------
```

I need a query to select all categories along with the number of products for each for a specific time range in which those products were created (`CreatedDate`).

What I currently have is this:

```
SELECT c.[Name], COUNT(p.[Id]) AS ProductCount
FROM Categories AS c
LEFT JOIN Products AS p ON p.[CategoryId] = c.[Id]
WHERE p.[CreatedDate] BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-06-01'
GROUP BY c.[Name]
```

My issue is that I'm not seeing `Category2` and `Category3` in the results set because they don't pass the `WHERE` clause. I want to see all categories in the results set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the  `where` condition in the `left join` clause

```
SELECT c.[Name], COUNT(p.[Id]) AS ProductCount
FROM Categories AS c
LEFT JOIN Products AS p ON p.[CategoryId] = c.[Id]
                       AND p.[CreatedDate] BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-06-01'
GROUP BY c.[Name]
```

This way it is applied to the join only and not to the complete result set.

Comment: Damn I forgot you can do that. Thanks!